# how to call parent method with dependencies in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use `div` with `ng-click` for routing:

`ng-click="go('/item/{{item.id}}'`).

I can call `$parent.go` or even `go` when using `ParentCtrl`. But `ParentCtrl_2` does not work at all. I tried to look for some answers, but can't figure it out. What am I missing?

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.go = function(path) {
            console.log(path);
        }
    }
);

app.controller('ParentCtrl_2', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.go = function(path) {
            $location.path(path);
        }
    }
]);

app.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
        ...
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are number of unanswered questions here but, like what is the structure of your html `ng-controller` structure.

Also the call sytax in html is wrong for

`ng-click="go('/item/{{item.id}}')`

It should be

```
ng-click="go('/item/'+ item.id)"
```

Said that depending on where the `ng-click` is declared it would have access to parent methods. If you can access a method using `$parent` then you can access the method directly due to prototypal inheritance.

If structure is like

```
<div ng-controller='ParentCtrl'>
    <div ng-controller='ParentCtrl_2'>
           <div ng-controller='ChildCtrl'>
                  <!-- ng-click somewhere here -->
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you access the `ParentCtrl_2` method `go` whenever you call.

If it is

```
    <div ng-controller='ParentCtrl'>
        <div ng-controller='ParentCtrl_2'>

        </div>
        <div ng-controller='ChildCtrl'>
            <!-- ng-click somewhere here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then you have access to `ParentCtrl` method `go` method only.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. There is actually only one parent controller at a time. But when I am using the syntax of `ParentCtrl_2`, ie. declaring dependencies in `[]`, the child does not see the parent's method `go`. I have actually found out that I can do: `app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope,$location){}`.